# React Router v6 - Push & Pop state action

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

In the latest react-router v6, `useHistory()` hook has been replaced by `useNavigate()`, well what I wanted is, I want to get the `action` object to know, it was **'Push'** or **'Pop'** state, `useHistory` had this object, but in latest v6, I couldn't find where I can get this object can anyone guide me please, I'm working on page animation i need this action state to define the animation seamlessly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but... Maybe `useNavigationType()` hook is what you're looking for? https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigation-type

Comment: You probably looking for `const navigate = useNavigate(); ()=>navigate(-1)`

Answer (score 4):

See [useNavigationType](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation-type).

TypeScript example:

```
import { Action } from 'history';
import { NavigationType, useNavigationType } from 'react-router-dom';
// ... other imports

const MyComponent = () => {
  const navType: NavigationType = useNavigationType();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(navType);
    if (navType === Action.Pop) {
      // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
  }, [navType]);

  return (
    <div>my UI</div>
  );
};
```